# Помощь в разборе ошибки python

Tags: python

Есть небольшой код с использованием стороннего api(кому интересно - pip install pyopendota). Суть api в получении той или иной информации о игроках/матчах дота2. При попытке реализации кода, питон выдает ошибку, которую я, в виду своей неопытности понять никак не могу.

Вот ошибка:

1. Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "H:\pythonProject1\proverkasinputom.py", line 15, in 
   y = str(client.get_player(x))
2. File "H:\Pythonn\lib\site-packages\opendota\opendota.py", line 425, in get_player
   return self.get(url, filename=filename, force=force)
3. File "H:\Pythonn\lib\site-packages\opendota\opendota.py", line 227, in get return self.request(*args, **kwargs)
4. File "H:\Pythonn\lib\site-packages\opendota\opendota.py", line 216, in request
   with open(path, "w") as f:
   OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Users\Shaurma\dota2\player_480484126\n.json'

Вот код, который приводит к данной ошибке:

```
while True:
    if count == 1:
        print('done')
        break
    file1 = open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    x = file1.readline()
    file1.close()
    y = client.get_player(x)
    print(y)
    count += 1
```

При этом, если я прописываю вручную id в  `client.get_player`, все прекрасно работает.
Пример рабочего кода, но без подстановки нужного id через переменную:

```
count = 0
while True:
    if count == 1:
        print('done')
        break
    y = client.get_player('480484126')
    print(y)
    count += 1
```

Хотелось бы понять: это какое-то ограничение api на ввод id через переменную,или что-то иное? Есть ли возможное решение данного вопроса?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: И у вас ошибка на файл, открываемый с "w", а код - с "r". Плохая практика.

Comment: @Сергей Это библиотека пытается писать инфу в файл, так что может всё и нормально. Хотя и странно выглядит, что библиотека пишет в файл, а не просто возвращает данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File "H:\Pythonn\lib\site-packages\opendota\opendota.py", 
line 216, in request with open(path, "w") as f: 
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
'C:\\Users\\Shaurma\\dota2\\player_480484126\n.json'
                                            ^^
```

Судя по ошибке, у вас передаётся в вызов `api` лишний перевод строки после номера игрока. Попробуйте его убрать:

```py
x = file1.readline().strip()
                    ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: CrazyElf, спасибо. Действительно, это решило проблему. Бился над ней 2 дня :) Ну, на то я и новичок, чтобы в простых вещах, пока что, копаться долго

Comment: @wooooble Вы зря только убрали двойные бэкслэши из пути файла с ошибкой, если бы я не увидел, что в начале идут двойные бэкслэши `\\\`, а потом одиночный с n `\n`, я бы не догадался почему ошибка )